# Loop through large data set back-end development

Tags: node.js, algorithm, parallel-processing, backend, bigdata

I am new to back-end development. I am dealing with unstructured data. I have to process 10,000 json objects to get output. Now, I am fetching from database and loop through each one and finding the result and it's taking more time to send response. How to do this actually ? which technology should we use ?
Is this Big data problem ? or any parallel processing required ? Need to use any library ? Currently developing in nodejs. please give me suggestions or help .

Comment: can you upload some code what you have tried ?

Comment: can you show me your code

Comment: its just a for loop through  data set. of json objects .with size 10k

Comment: We can't answer your question properly because it is lacking details. What kind of processing do you do? Can it be parallelized? What technology are you using? What database are you fetching from? It's not really a big data problem as it seems.

Comment: i m working on elasticsearch database, unstructured data ..in node.js..and it is not parallelized .. and synchronous task.